# Maximization of nonlinear equation in Java

Tags: java, math, mathematical-optimization, scientific-computing, nonlinear-functions

I want to determine the value of x for which a certain function (similar to the next one) is maximized:
[image]

It is clear that the maximum of A is reached when x = 0, and then A = 200.

How could I solve this problem in Java?

Update: Sorry for not making it clear from the beginning. x is an int, but I need a method to find the maximum also when x is not upper bounded like in the next example:
[image]

Comment: if x is an integer, the question is trivial, if it is not, the objective in question is non-convex and non-differentiable, therefore there is no general way of determining the maximum *exactly*

Comment: Can you describe exactly what functions you need to maximise? They only contain floor and multiplication, addition and substraction?

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov yes, they should contain only floor, multiplication, addition and substraction

Answer (score 2):

The floor function has a linear upper bound as well as a lower one, `x-1 < floor(x) < x`, which should make it possible to determine the general shape of the curve. One could then find the maximum of the lower bound (which is a linear function) and enumerate the values of `x` which fall into the area where the upper bound of `A` may reach the maximum of the lower bound, namely the regions where the upper bound exceeds the minimum of the lower bound.
If this region in question is finite, the `x` that maximizes the `A` can thus be found. If it is not, this indicates that the function is cyclic, and therefore you have to determine its period and find the maximum on the period.

In the example, the lower bound would be `(x + 100) / 1000 - 1 + 3 * (x / 1000 - 1) + 200 - x`, which is equal to `(196100 - 996 * x) / 1000`, and the upper bound `(x + 100) / 1000 + 3 * (x / 1000) + 200 - x` or `(200100 - 996 * x) / 1000`. The lower bound obviously reaches its maximum of `196100 / 1000` at `x == 0` and therefore we need only check those values of x where the upper bound is higher, `(200100 - 996 * x) / 1000 > 196100 / 1000`, which can be reduced to `x < 4.02`, so one only has to check the values of `x` from 0 to 4.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `floor((x+100)/1000)` and `floor(x/1000)` are both `0` for the given range.  That makes this example pretty easy.

p.s. I don't think Java has anything to do with this question.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Didn't see that `x` has to be an integer.

If someone has a function where the variables do not have to be integers, they can use the following:

To approximate the maximum, you could have a look at the [Nelder-Mead method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method). It is susceptible to local maxima and requires a smooth function. It is implemented in [Flanagan's Java Scientific Library](http://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~mflanaga/java/Maximisation.html). Basically you have to extend `MaximizationFunction` and implement the function

```
public double function(double[] param)
```

which contains your function above. This method evaluates your function given the parameters `param` (in your case one value: `x`) and returns the function value.

Then you can use the whole program like this:

```
//Create instance of Maximisation
Maximization max = new Maximization();

// Create instace of class holding function to be maximised
YourFunction funct = new YourFunction();

// initial estimates (your initial x)
double[] start = {30.0};

// initial step sizes (take a good guess)
double[] step = new double[start.length];
Arrays.fill(step, 100);

// convergence tolerance
double ftol = 0.0001;

// maximal number of iterations
int maxIter = 5000;

// Nelder and Mead maximisation procedure
max.nelderMead(funct, start, step, ftol, maxIter);

// result of maximization
double result = max.getMaximum()
```

Since your variable has restrictions, you should add some constraints via the `addConstraint` method of `Maximization`.

Comment: the goal is for him to implement the calculation.  It's scientific computation....

Comment: @hvgotcodes Would you mind withdrawing your downvote, since we are not sure about his goal?

Comment: This method optimizes the objective as if x was a real number, which it is not. Moreover, most iterative methods don't work well with discontinuous functions.

Comment: @MikhailKozhevnikov Fair enough, I will still keep this answer here, for those having a similar problem.

Comment: First, thanks for your answers. Second, is there an iterative method that works also for x being integer?

Answer (score 0):

here is an outline, since this is homework

```
public int myMax(int x){ // assuming x is an integer
  // implement the math function as a Java function 
  // Java has a floor function
}

public int findMaxOverRange(int low, int hi) {
    int highestSoFar = 0;
    for (int x = low; x <= hi; x++) {
       // invoke your function, getting the result.  If the result is higher
       // than highestSoFar, reset highestSoFar to the value.
    }
}
```

The [floor function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor%28double%29)

Comment: What if answer is not integer?

Comment: its an integer -- look at the floor functions

Answer (score -1):

In java you basically study whole field of mathematical optimization and implement some algorithm in java (as in any other language).
Java doesn't have any so specific math tools. You can search for libraries.